# How can I search for two different patterns in two consecutive lines in a file using SED and print next 4 lines after pattern match?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am using SED and looking for printing the line matched by pattern and next 4 lines after the pattern match.

Below is the summary of my issue.
"myfile.txt" content has:

```
As specified in doc.
risk involved in astra.
I am not a schizophrenic;and neither am I.;
Be polite to every idiot you meet.;He could be your boss tomorrow.;
I called the hospital;but the line was dead.;
Yes, I’ve lost to my computer at chess.;But it turned out to be no match for me at kickboxing.;
The urologist is about to leave his office and says:; "Ok, let's piss off now.";
What's the best place to hide a body?;Page two of Google.;
You know you’re old;when your friends start having kids on purpose.;
You won’t find anything more poisonous;than a harmonious;and friendly group of females.;
Two state clerks meet in the corridor.;One asks the other,;"Couldn't sleep either?";
Why do women put on make-up and perfume?;Because they are ugly and they smell.;
Bruce Lee’s all-time favorite drink?;Wataaaaaaaah!;
Daddy what is a transvestite?;-Ask Mommy, he knows.;
That moment when you have eye contact while eating a banana.;
```

I'm using below command.

```
sed -n -e '/You/h' -e '/Two/{x;G;p}' myfile.txt
```

Output by my command:

```
You won’t find anything more poisonous;than a harmonious;and friendly group of females.;
Two state clerks meet in the corridor.;One asks the other,;"Couldn't sleep either?";
```

Desired output:

```
You won’t find anything more poisonous;than a harmonious;and friendly group of females.;
Two state clerks meet in the corridor.;One asks the other,;"Couldn't sleep either?";
Why do women put on make-up and perfume?;Because they are ugly and they smell.;
Bruce Lee’s all-time favorite drink?;Wataaaaaaaah!;
Daddy what is a transvestite?;-Ask Mommy, he knows.;
That moment when you have eye contact while eating a banana.;
```

Comment: `awk '/You/{ getline;x=$0}  /Two/ {print x ORS $0;for(i=1;i<=4;i++) {getline ;print $0} }'  inputfile`  , this worked for me. but people says not to use `getline`. so avoid and not putting it in as answer.

Comment: how about `grep -A 5 "You won" myfile.txt` ?

Comment: I need to match two patterns 'You on first line and Two on second line respectively.' As I have many You won't statements that I don't want,

Comment: pluse-uno for well constructed Q! Thanks for including input/required output/current code/current output.  Keep posting and good luck to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/You/h;{/Two/{x;G;};//,+4p}' myfile.txt
```

Output:

```
You won’t find anything more poisonous;than a harmonious;and friendly group of females.;                                                                                                                                                     
Two state clerks meet in the corridor.;One asks the other,;"Couldn't sleep either?";                                                                                                                                                         
Why do women put on make-up and perfume?;Because they are ugly and they smell.;                                                                                                                                                              
Bruce Lee’s all-time favorite drink?;Wataaaaaaaah!;                                                                                                                                                                                          
Daddy what is a transvestite?;-Ask Mommy, he knows.;                                                                                                                                                                                         
That moment when you have eye contact while eating a banana.;
```

**Explanation:**

- `/You/h`: copy matching line into the hold space. As there is only one hold space, `h` will store the last line matching `You` (ie `You won’t...`)
- `/Two/{x`: when `Two` is found, `x` exchange the pattern space with the hold space. At this point:

  **into pattern space**: `You won’t find anything more poisonous;than a harmonious;and friendly group of females.;`

  **into hold space**: `Two state clerks meet in the corridor.;One asks the other,;"Couldn't sleep either?";`
- `G`: appends a new line to the pattern space  and copies the hold space after the new line
- `//,+4p` is an address range starting from `//` (empty address repeats the last regular expression match, ie first 2 lines matching), up to next 4 lines `+4`. The address range is output with `p`

Comment: good one! this would work for arbitrary number of lines after match, for ex: `98` as mentioned by OP in comments..

Comment: I'm trying the decipher what you have written but not able to get how it is doing it? Please help and explain.

Comment: Thankyou very much... @Kenavoz You rock. I understand it now.

Comment: Does this match `You` and `Two` in consecutive lines?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this help you;

```
sed -n -e '/You/h' -e '/Two/{N;N;N;N;x;G;p}' myfile.txt
```

Example;

```
user@host:/tmp$ sed -n -e '/You/h' -e '/Two/{N;N;N;N;x;G;p}' myfile.txt
You won’t find anything more poisonous;than a harmonious;and friendly group of females.;
Two state clerks meet in the corridor.;One asks the other,;"Couldn't sleep either?";
Why do women put on make-up and perfume?;Because they are ugly and they smell.;
Bruce Lee’s all-time favorite drink?;Wataaaaaaaah!;
Daddy what is a transvestite?;-Ask Mommy, he knows.;
That moment when you have eye contact while eating a banana.;
```

Comment: Hi Muzido, Thanks.  Do I have to specify N;N;N;N; for it 4 times? Isn't there any way to add 4N; kind of stuff. For another keywords I have to print 98 lines. Do I have to write 98 times N; for it?

Comment: Does this match You and Two in consecutive lines?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;/You.*\n.*Two/{:a;$!{N;s/\n/&/4;Ta};p;d};D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space, pattern match and then print four further lines (if possible). Otherwise, delete the first line and repeat.